# Retrieve Information from the wikipedia infobox with R

Tags: html, r, wikipedia

Even in light of all the informations available I see myself unable to solve the following issue (while admitting that I'm way out of my field of expertice...)

What I want: To retrieve data from the Wikipedia infobox in articles about cities. To Keep it simple: I want the Population of Trüllikon, an Information within the Infobox of the respective Wikipedia-article.

What I have so far by consulting related questions here:

```
library("RCurl")
library("XML")

link <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%BCllikon"
site <- getURL(link)
site <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(site)); close(tc)

psite <- htmlTreeParse(site, error=function(...){}, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

in the object `psite` I see the following lines:

```
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; border-right: 1px solid #eee;">Einwohner:</td>
<td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;"><span style="white-space:nowrap;">1014 <small>(31. Dezember 2015)</small><sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-1">[1]</a></sup></span></td>
</tr>
```

So 1014 People ("Einwohner" in German) are living in Trüllikon but I have no clue how to access this information... I thought about the `xpathSApply`-function (seen in an related question), but I was unable to adapt it to my problem

Any help would be much appreciated

**Update**

```
pop <- link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[1]') %>%
  html_table()

r1 <- pop[[1]][ which(pop[[1]][,1] == "Einwohner:"),2]
r1
[1] "1014 (31. Dezember 2015)[1]"

(r1 <- sub(" .*", "", r1))
[1] "1014"
```

It's probably not the most elegant solution and not sure yet if this will hold up of other cities. For example, If I'm interested in the City of Schlieren the reference to the first table above is not the correct one (in this case because the title "Schlieren" isn't unique in Wikipedia).

```
link <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr%C3%BCllikon"
link2 <- "https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/schlieren"

pop <- link %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()

pop2 <- link2 %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_table()

# I'm interested in the first list for "Trüllikon"
str(pop)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':       16 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Trüllikon: chr [1:16] "" "Staat:" "Kanton:" "Bezirk:" ...
  ..$ Trüllikon: chr [1:16] "" "Schweiz" "Zürich (ZH)" "Andelfingenw" ...
 $ :'data.frame':       7 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Bevölkerungsentwicklung: chr [1:7] "Jahr" "1950" "1960" "1970" ...
  ..$ Bevölkerungsentwicklung: chr [1:7] "Einwohner" "895" "823" "724" ...
 $ :'data.frame':       1 obs. of  1 variable:

# I'm interested in the second list for "Schlieren"
str(pop2)
List of 3
 $ :'data.frame':       1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ X1: logi NA
  ..$ X2: chr "Der Titel dieses Artikels ist mehrdeutig. Weitere Bedeutungen sind unter Schlieren (Begriffsklärung) aufgeführt."
 $ :'data.frame':       18 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ Schlieren: chr [1:18] "" "Staat:" "Kanton:" "Bezirk:" ...
  ..$ Schlieren: chr [1:18] "" "Schweiz" "Zürich (ZH)" "Dietikon" ...
 $ :'data.frame':       1 obs. of  1 variable:
```

Comment: I don't have much time (code's compiling^^), but maybe this helps: https://github.com/brry/misc/blob/master/API%20challenge.R#L45

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have to go through you Code thoroughly, but in combination with https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-rvest-to-scrape-an-html-table/ it led to the solution updated above